# What tool is better for journal-quality plots: matplotlib or Matlab?

Tags: publications, writing, graphics, formatting

I make my plots in Matlab and they turn out looking reasonably good. However, I'm contemplating porting to more open-source tools and hence, I wish to make use of Python's matplotlib.

My priorities are:

1. Making beautiful, professional, journal-quality plots as vector-graphics to be imported into a LaTeX document
2. Being able to modify almost all aspects of the plot

I mostly make scatter, line and Box & Whisker plots.

Given these considerations, which among the two tools: Matlab or matplotlib is better and should I port to Python-matplotlib?

Comment: The tool you know and use is the best tool.

Comment: That seems eminently opinion-based given that you can do everything with both tools.

Comment: For simple plots, you can use [matplotlib2tikz](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib2tikz/), which gives you native TikZ/PGFplots code.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much difference between them since matplotlib has tried to emulate the matlab design of figures. However, matplotlib has evolved a bit more giving you additional choices (e.g. seaborn), but you have to learn how to use them.

If you are using LaTeX, then save and embedd the figures as pdf files and  use pdflatex for your latexing. This is the standard way of using LaTeX at least in Computer Science. Both tools allow you to create pdf files from figures.